# Sending ether to a payable function in Solidity doesn't decrease the sender's Ether in Ganache

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, payable

I have the following smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./MyCoinSupply.sol";

contract MyCoinDEX
{
    IERC20 public token;

    event Bought(uint256 amount);
    event Sold(uint256 amount);

    constructor() public
    {
        token = new MyCoinSupply();
    }

    function getSenderAddress() public view returns (address) // for debugging purposes
    {
        return (msg.sender);
    }

    function getAddress() public view returns (address)
    {
        return address(this);
    }

    function getTokenAddress() public view returns (address)
    {
        return address(token);
    }

    function buy() payable public // send ether and get tokens in exchange; 1 token == 1 ether
    {
      uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
      uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
      require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some ether");
      require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
      token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);
      emit Bought(amountTobuy);
    }

    function sell(uint256 amount) public // send tokens to get ether back
    {
      require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
      uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
      require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
      token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341914/error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-payable
      payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
      emit Sold(amount);
    }

}
```

if I call the `buy()` method from `truffle console`, it executes without any exceptions:

```
truffle(development)> MyCoinDEX.buy({value: 1})
```

I verified that the account calling the `buy()` method receives the token. **However, the balance of Ether in Ganache for the account calling the `buy()` method doesn't decrease.** So essentially, the account is getting tokens for free.

**What's going on here? How do I fix it?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Ether and Wei.

```
truffle(development)> MyCoinDEX.buy({value: 1})
```

the value property is in Wei as everything on the ethereum network, so you are sending one Wei or 0.000000000000000001 Ether.

The ganache display precision doesn't necessarily cover the 18 decimals so you may not even see any change...

> So essentially, the account is getting tokens for free.

Not quite, but for very cheap at least !

If you want to send 1 ETH, set a value of : 1000000000000000000 Wei.